# Changing navigation bar image - not working

Tags: ios, image, background, uinavigationbar

I'd like to change the background image (or color) of the navigation bar, but for some reason it's not working.

I've searched around, and found that on iOS 5.0+ (I'm running 6.1) this should work:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:navigationBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Now none of those work. Also tried with:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Now I'm thinking that I'm assigning it to the wrong object, but this works:

```
UIImageView *titleImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scr1_title"]];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleImage;
```

Comment: Just a small question, are you user a `UINavigationController` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code in your view controller to change the navigation bar background image.

```
 if([[UINavigationBar class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) //iOS >=5.0
    {
        UIImage * navBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] ;
        [[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundImage: navBarImage  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the tint color on the navigation bar of the navigation controller. Make sure you select the correct on as shown in the screenshot below.
 [image: Screenshot]

1. Select your storyboard in the file browser.
2. Select the navigation controller in the storyboard.
3. In the Document Outline (second column) select the navigation bar of the navigation controller.
4. In the Utilities view (column on the right) adjust the tint color.
5. Click on the root view controller to the right on the navigation controller. It will pick up the new color after you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

To set the image..
Write this code

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

inside

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
}
```